# Copy&Paste the data①② without convert data type

Tags: xml, csv, copy-paste

Im in trouble. Help me, please.

《What I want to do》
I want to export the data①② from certain system in CSV format, 
open the CSV file, 
copy that data①②, 
and paste that to one cell of the XML file.

《Data》
The data are follwing two.
Data①: 2/8
Data②: ABC(line feed)DEF

《Problems》
Problem1: Data① including slash is recognized as a date or numeric value.
I exporte the data①② from the system to a CSV file, data① is recognized as a date when the CSV file is opened.
Furthermore,  if I copy&paste data① from the CSV file to the XML file, data① is recognized as a number.

Problem2: Data② including a line feed code can't be stored in one cell.
To avoid problem1, I open that CSV file as TXT file. However, data② can't be stored in one cell, because the data② includes line feed code.

Comment: 《 Is 》this① a document containing linear records①②?

Comment: Data①,Data② are text data in the document.